# How to pass custom data to HandleChallengeAsync

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Web API with a custom authenication scheme that reads auth tokens. Authentication can fail (401) for a number of reasons (token missing, invalid, expired), so I'd like to be able to indicate the failure reason in the HTTP response. E.g., `401 Token has expired`.

Tokens are parsed and validated in `AuthenticationHandler<T>.HandleAuthenticateAsync`. How do I pass the failure reason from that method to `HandleChallengeAsync`?

```
protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
{
  AuthenticateResult result = null;
  var tokenResult = this.ParseToken(this.Request, out var token);

  if (tokenResult == TokenResult.Normal)
  {
    result = AuthenticateResult.Success(this.ticketFactory.CreateAuthenticationTicket(token));
  }
  else
  {
    result = AuthenticateResult.Fail("Bad token");
    // FIXME: Figure out how to populate the Properties property
    //result.Properties.Items.Add(nameof(TokenResult), tokenResult.ToString());
  }

  return Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

`AuthenticationProperties.Items` looks like a good place to store this type of custom data. But I can't figure out how to create an `AuthenticationProperties` object inside of `HandleAuthenticateAsync` and attach it to an `AuthenticateResult` object. Is there a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The authentication handler is transient-scoped, as you can see here in the source code: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/4dd2a883a4b22cf3df5944b1224355a94158f516/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationBuilder.cs#L48

Every request will get their own instance of the handler, so you can set the failure reason as an instance field.

Comment: Add a field on the handler class, assign it from HandleAuthenticateAsync and use it from HandleChallengeAsync.

Comment: After the consolidation of .NET GitHub repos the source code is here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationBuilder.cs#L48.